# Make a slot call a virtual function

Tags: qt, qt4

I would like to have a slot that calls the function of the appropriate subclass. Here is a demo:

```
#ifndef CALCULATORFORM_H
#define CALCULATORFORM_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include <iostream>

#include "ui_form.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow, public Ui::MainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

signals:
  void valueChanged(int);

private slots:
  void on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value)
  {
    SliderValueChanged(value);
  }

public:
  MainWindow(QMainWindow *parent = 0)
  {
    this->setupUi(this);
    bool success = connect(this->horizontalSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int)));
    std::cout << "Success? " << success << std::endl;
  }

//private:
  virtual void SliderValueChanged(const int value)
  {
    std::cout << "MainWindow" << std::endl;
  }
};

class FloatSlider : public MainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
  FloatSlider(QMainWindow *parent = 0) : MainWindow(parent){this->setupUi(this);}

private:
  void SliderValueChanged(const int value)
  {
    std::cout << "FLOAT" << std::endl;
  }
};


#endif
```

If I use a MainWindow, it correctly outputs "MainWindow" when the slider is moved. However, if I use a FloatSlider, nothing is output. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How do you connect on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged?

Comment: I edited the original question to use an explicit connect() call. It returns true. Still, if the child class is used nothing is output when the slider is moved.

Comment: I added the same connect() call in the FloatSlider constructor and then it worked. Shouldn't that connect call have been made since the FloatSlider constructor calls the MainWindow constructor? Is this extra function (virtual) supposed to be necessary to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you call `setupUi` in both the `MainWindow` constructor and the `FloatSlider` constructor. But `FloatSlider` doesn't have its own ui part, it inherits the one from `MainWindow`.

So you setup the ui in the `MainWindow` constructor and make the connection. Then in the `FloatSlider` constructor, that follows when the `MainWindow` constructor is done, you call `setupUi` again, which overwrites the ui objects (or rather the respective pointers, as the components are all dynamically created) with new ones, which now don't have a connection. That is the reason why it works when you call `connect` in the `FloatSlider` constructor, too. But of course it still creates the memory leak (the objects from the first `setupUi` call are lost). Actually the old objects may get cleaned up by Qt because they still have `this` as parent, but they are just useless, as they're either hanging around nowhere (if the window has a top-level layout, which is overwritten in `setupUi` instead of added) or they're duplicated (if the window has no top-level layout).

So just remove this `setupUi` call from `FloatSlider`'s constructor. Since `MainWindow` inherits from `Ui::MainWindow` and `FloatSlider` doesn't add anything that `setupUi` cares about, it's `MainWindow`'s responsibility to call `setupUi`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. Ok, after removing the setupUi call, the slot that is called is still in MainWindow (when using a FloatSlider object). Is what I did at first (making a non-slot virtual function and calling it from the MainWindow slot) the correct way to do this?

Comment: Yes indeed. But from [Qt's documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/signalsandslots.html) it seems you can just make the slot itself virtual. Then `FloatSlider`'s slot should be called, even if you call the `connect` in `MainWindow`s constructor. But I'm not sure about that. Maybe you have to call the `connect` in `FloatSlider`'s constructor then or maybe virtual dispatch just doesn't work when called through a signal. In this case your solution is the way to go. But nevertheless, call `setupUi` only once, and preferably in `MainWindow`'s constructor.

Comment: Ahhh the slot can be virtual! Thanks, that does the job :)